# how to call method using spring?

Tags: spring, methods

I want to call a method after creating the bean using spring, for example  I create `Factory` and schema but I want to call the same method of `Factory` before creating a schema bean

```
 <!-- schemaFactory-->
    <bean id="schemaFact" class="javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory"
        factory-method="newInstance">
        <constructor-arg value="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
    </bean>

<!-- schema -->
    <bean id="schema" class="javax.xml.validation.Schema"
        factory-bean="schemaFact" factory-method="newSchema">
        <constructor-arg value="3DSecure.xsd" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.0/3.1 you can take advantage of Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    public SchemaFactory schemaFact() throws SAXNotSupportedException, SAXNotRecognizedException {
        final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        schemaFactory.setFeature("apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", false);
        return schemaFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public Schema schema() throws SAXException {
        return schemaFact().newSchema(new File("3DSecure.xsd"));
    }
}
```

But which method on `SchemaFactory` do you want to call? <del>Seems like all of them are either getters or setters, so you can use normal XML injection...</del> Alternatively create your own `FactoryBean`:

```
class SchemaFactoryFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<SchemaFactory> {

    @Override
    public SchemaFactory getObject() throws Exception
    {
        final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        schemaFactory.setFeature("apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", false);
        return schemaFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType()
    {
        return SchemaFactory.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And use it like this (no `factory-method` needed):

```
<bean id="schemaFact" class="SchemaFactoryFactoryBean"/>
```

Comment: thanks, i want call a setFeature(
"http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking",
false);
but this isn't a property !

Answer (score 2):

You could use your own factory bean instead of `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory`, which will delegate to `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory` and the call the method:

```
public class MySchemaFactory {
    public SchemaFactory newInstance() {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance();
        factory.callSomeMethod();
        return factory;
    }
}

<bean id="mySchemaFactory" class="com.foo.bar.MySchemaFactory"/>

<bean id="schemaFact"
      factory-bean="mySchemaFactory"
      factory-method="newInstance"/>
```